# Asynchronous image loading in a uitableview

Tags: ios, facebook, uitableview, uiimageview

I'm currently integrating Facebook in my application and I'm currently at the point where I'm loading the profile pictures of the friends of the loggedin user. I'm presenting these users in a UITableView, in each cell the picture and the name of the friend. I've subclassed UIImageView and when the corresponding cell is handled in the cellForView method, the image is loaded asynchronously.

However, when I scroll up and down several times, the image is flickering, first some wrong pictures are loaded, displayed for a very short time and then the right image is loaded. So I think that i have to look for a way to stop the loading of the image when the cell is outside the view.

Is there anyone who can help me with this problem and give me a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you share some code where you are setting the images? There is a much better way of doing this than not reusing cells!

Comment: hey one suggestion you can cache those images and when you completed your work with those images clear your cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider not reusing cells. This could, however, impair performance if you have a lot of table cells that need to be loaded (e.g., lot of friends). Since every cell has its own image, flickering won't occur because of cell reusing.

Another thing to look at is the file size of the images. Chances are they're bigger than the size you're actually showing them at. If there's a way to get a smaller version, that would definitely help, too.

Third, you can set the image view to a default image in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath`. The flickering will probably still occur, but with a default image, that looks better than if it's someone else's picture. In fact, I think this is what the Facebook app does.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have it working now by not reusing the cells :)

Comment: You should really reuse cells!

Answer (score 4):

You can dismiss any loaded image (as well as an ongoing loading operation, if there is one) in
 `- (void)prepareForReuse method of UITableViewCell`.

I would strongly recommend to reuse cells, there is no chance you'll get nice smooth scrolling without it.

Comment: please, be more detailed, what do I have to do in the prepareForReuse method?

Comment: You should cancel image loading operation and clear the image view (for example, assign null or some placeholder to it).
In ios6 you can also use tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method.

Answer (score 0):

When cell becomes hidden it is removed from the `tableView`. So you can override in your `UITableViewCell` derived class method `willMoveToSuperview:`

```
- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview
{
    [super willMoveToSuperview:newSuperview];
    if(newSuperview == nil) {
        // Stop image downloading
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I've tried to implement this but it didn't work very well, I had the same problem as before ;)